# Bind to property of a child in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, parent-child

I have a object **CellContent** with the properties *Text* and *BackgroundColor*. With the **CellContent** objects I created a list of **Persons** with the properties *FirstName* and *LastName*. I bound this list to a DataGrid. What I like to do, is to set the background color according to the Brush property.

The code below works well for the specific property *LastName* but I want to set it for *FirstName* too.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG">
     <DataGrid.CellStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
             <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding LastName.Background}" />
         </Style>
     </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

So the question is, how do I bind to child of the **CellContent** object in XAML or how can I replace LastName with some kind of wildcard?

Comment: set CellStyle individually for each column

Comment: Setting individualy column styles would help for this small example, but is there a more flexible solution?

Comment: @ASh: Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the AutoGeneratingColumn event to assign the Background property while generating the table. The DataGrid XAML now looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="DG" AutoGeneratingColumn="DG_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

and the code behind:

```
private void DG_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{                        
   DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
   textColumn.Header = e.Column.Header;
   textColumn.Binding = new Binding(e.Column.Header.ToString());

   textColumn.CellStyle = new Style();
   textColumn.CellStyle.TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell);
   textColumn.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new Binding(e.Column.Header + ".Background")));

   (sender as DataGrid).Columns.Add(textColumn);

   // Prevent autogenerating the columns
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This is certainly not the best solution but it solved my problem.